# regex in Perl to replace content containing double equal signs

Tags: regex, perl

I need a regex in Perl to turn this:

```
(== doc_url html/arbitrary_file_name.html ==)
```

into this:

```
(/doc_assets/legacy/html/arbitrary_file_name.html)
```

I've tried all kinds of things.  My current attempt looks like this:

```
$content =~ s!\=\= doc_url ([\w\W]+?)\=\=!/doc_assets/legacy/$1!gis;
```

(In this particular attempt, I'm just letting the enclosing parentheses remain, since that doesn't change from the input to the output.)

Anyway, nothing is working for me.  I assume it's the `==` throwing things off.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing special about `=` in regular expressions, it shouldn't throw it off.

Comment: Your code works for me, except there's a space between `.html` and `)` in the result. That's because `([\w\W]+?)` matches the space after the filename.

Comment: The regex can be reduced to [`s!==\s*doc_url\s*(.+?)\s*==!/doc_assets/legacy/$1!gis`](https://regex101.com/r/jF3qC2/1)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need something like:

```
s!.*?doc_url (.*?/.*?) .*!(/doc_assets/legacy/$1)!sg
```

---

**i.e.:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$subject = "(== doc_url html/arbitrary_file_name.html ==)";
$subject =~ s!.*?doc_url (.*?/.*?) .*!(/doc_assets/legacy/$1)!sg;
print $subject;
#(/doc_assets/legacy/html/arbitrary_file_name.html)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/quzHVu)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
.*?doc_url (.*?/.*?) .*

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Numbered capture

Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “doc_url ” literally (case sensitive) «doc_url »
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?/.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “/” literally «/»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match any single character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»

(/doc_assets/legacy/$1)

Insert the character string “(/doc_assets/legacy/” literally «(/doc_assets/legacy/»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the character “)” literally «)»
```